# Changing WordPress Footer Dimensions - CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to tweak the footer of a Wordpress theme but to no avail. Here is the code for the footer in  in the file footer.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying the footer.
 *
 * Contains the closing of the #content div and all content after
 *
 * @package vslmd
 */
?>
<?php 

//Variables > Theme Options

$options = get_option('vslmd_options');    
$footerColumns = $options['footer_widget_columns']; 
$footer_color_scheme = $options['footer_color_scheme']; 
$footer_text = $options['footer_text']; 
$footer_breadcrumbs = $options['footer_breadcrumbs']; 

?>



<div class="footer-background-image">

    <div class="wrapper wrapper-footer footer-background-color <?php     echo $footer_color_scheme; ?>">

        <div class="container">

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-12">

                    <footer id="colophon" class="site-footer" role="contentinfo">

                        <?php if ( !is_front_page() && $footer_breadcrumbs == '1' ) { ?>
                        <div class="top-footer col-md-12">
                            <div class="breadcrumbs-footer col-md-9">
                                <?php if (function_exists('vslmd_breadcrumbs')) vslmd_breadcrumbs(); ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="bottom-to-top col-md-3 text-right">
                                <span><i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php } elseif ( is_front_page() || ( $footer_breadcrumbs != '' || $footer_breadcrumbs != '0' ) ) { ?>
                        <div class="top-footer col-md-12">
                            <div class="bottom-to-top text-center">
                                <span><i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php } ?>

                        <div class="widgets-footer">
                        <?php

                        get_template_part('widget-templates/before-footer');

                    if($footerColumns == '1'){ ?>

                        <div class="col-md-12">
                        <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'first-footer' ) ) { ?>
                            <?php dynamic_sidebar('first-footer'); ?>
                        <?php } ?>
                        </div>

                    <?php } else if($footerColumns == '2'){ ?>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                        <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'first-footer' ) ) { ?>
                            <?php dynamic_sidebar('first-footer'); ?>
                        <?php } ?>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                        <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'second-footer' ) ) { ?>
                            <?php dynamic_sidebar('second-footer'); ?>
                        <?php } ?>
                        </div>

                    <?php } else if($footerColumns == '3'){ ?>

                        <div class="col-md-4">
                        <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'first-footer' ) ) { ?>
                            <?php dynamic_sidebar('first-footer'); ?>
                        <?php } ?>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-4">
                        <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'second-footer' ) ) { ?>
                            <?php dynamic_sidebar('second-footer'); ?>
                        <?php } ?>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-4">
                        <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'third-footer' ) ) { ?>
                            <?php dynamic_sidebar('third-footer'); ?>
                        <?php } ?>
                        </div>

                    <?php } else if($footerColumns == '4'){ ?>

                        <div class="col-md-3">
                        <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'first-footer' ) ) { ?>
                            <?php dynamic_sidebar('first-footer'); ?>
                        <?php } ?>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-3">
                        <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'second-footer' ) ) { ?>
                            <?php dynamic_sidebar('second-footer'); ?>
                        <?php } ?>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-3">
                        <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'third-footer' ) ) { ?>
                            <?php dynamic_sidebar('third-footer'); ?>
                        <?php } ?>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-3">
                        <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'fourth-footer' ) ) { ?>
                            <?php dynamic_sidebar('fourth-footer'); ?>
                        <?php } ?>
                        </div>

                    <?php } else if($footerColumns == '5'){ ?>

                        <div class="col-md-8">
                        <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'first-footer' ) ) { ?>
                            <?php dynamic_sidebar('first-footer'); ?>
                        <?php } ?>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-4">
                        <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'second-footer' ) ) { ?>
                            <?php dynamic_sidebar('second-footer'); ?>
                        <?php } ?>
                        </div>

                    <?php } else if($footerColumns == '6'){ ?>

                        <div class="col-md-4">
                        <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'first-footer' ) ) { ?>
                            <?php dynamic_sidebar('first-footer'); ?>
                        <?php } ?>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-8">
                        <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'second-footer' ) ) { ?>
                            <?php dynamic_sidebar('second-footer'); ?>
                        <?php } ?>
                        </div>

                    <?php } else if($footerColumns == '7'){ ?>

                        <div class="col-md-3">
                        <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'first-footer' ) ) { ?>
                            <?php dynamic_sidebar('first-footer'); ?>
                        <?php } ?>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                        <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'second-footer' ) ) { ?>
                            <?php dynamic_sidebar('second-footer'); ?>
                        <?php } ?>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-3">
                        <?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'third-footer' ) ) { ?>
                            <?php dynamic_sidebar('third-footer'); ?>
                        <?php } ?>
                        </div>

                    <?php } ?>

                    <?php get_template_part('widget-templates/after-footer'); ?>

                    </div>

                    <div class="site-info bottom-footer col-md-12">
                        <div class="row vertical-centering">
                        <div class="col-md-6 copyright-footer-item">
                        <?php if(empty($footer_text)) { ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( __( 'http://wordpress.org/', 'vslmd' ) ); ?>"><?php printf( __( 'Proudly powered by %s', 'vslmd' ), 'WordPress' ); ?></a>
                        <span class="sep"> | </span>
                        <?php printf( __( 'Theme: %1$s by %2$s.', 'vslmd' ), 'Mastergen', '<a href="https://visualmodo.com/" rel="designer">visualmodo.com</a>' ); ?>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                            <span><?php echo $footer_text ?></span>
                        <?php } ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php get_template_part('widget-templates/copyright-footer'); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- .site-info -->

                </footer><!-- #colophon -->

            </div><!--col end -->

        </div><!-- row end -->

    </div><!-- container end -->

    </div><!-- background color end -->

</div><!-- wrapper end -->

</div><!-- #page -->

<?php wp_footer(); ?>

</body>

</html>
```

In addition here is the code for the footer portion in the CSS file:

```
.wrapper-footer {
  background-color: #222328;
  padding: 2.5em; }
  .wrapper-footer .widget-footer-title {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    letter-spacing: 0.075rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6); }
  .wrapper-footer .widgets-footer ol,
  .wrapper-footer .widgets-footer ul {
    margin: 0 0 1.75em;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none; }
    .wrapper-footer .widgets-footer ol li,
    .wrapper-footer .widgets-footer ul li {
      padding: 0.250em 0; }
      .wrapper-footer .widgets-footer ol li a,
      .wrapper-footer .widgets-footer ul li a {
        color: #FFF; }
        .wrapper-footer .widgets-footer ol li a:hover,
        .wrapper-footer .widgets-footer ul li a:hover {
          color: #685d9f; }

footer .site-info.bottom-footer {
  border-top: 1px solid;
  padding-top: 2.250em;
  margin-top: 2.250em; }
```

I have tried changing any of the values and I still get no differences. Here's an image of what the footer actually looks like.

[Footer Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dv7L1.png)

What I want is to reduce the space between the different widgets and make the whole footer a lot more compact. What do I need to change in the HTML or CSS?

Thanks so much for your help!

Stefano

Comment: you need to post your HTML code too

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Always be specific and make your best effort before asking. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions. Please add your HTML code that is the structure over which we have to apply the CSS.

Comment: My apologies. I'm new to Stack Overflow and coding as well... You will notice I made the changes to the question. Thank you so much for your help!